# How to look up whether a verb uses dative or accusative

Tags: dative, accusative, dictionary, reference

Generally, my understanding of the use of dative and accusative is a bit opaque.  I am getting better at deciphering which prepositions call for which case.  I have also seen that motion is another indicator.  If I am not clear, however, is there a resource which I can use to look up a particular word?  (I use dict.cc a lot and I don't think it specifies.)  Usually I Google "German dative verbs" and use CTRL+F to search for the verb, then assume that if it's not found, it's accusative.

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=geben&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on   dictionaries do indicate it usually. (jmdn is acc, jmdm is dat)

Comment: Also [mein-deutschbuch.de](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=2) is a good resource to look up this kind of thing.

Comment: @Emanuel Ah, I didn't know that jmdn/m was the indicator.  Thanks.

Comment: It is not only about the verb. Sometimes accusative indicates motion and dative statics. For example `Ich lege das Buch auf den Tisch` aber `Das Buch liegt auf dem Tisch`. Poor you native English speakers, we Poles do have declination (7 cases, 3 more than in German!); we also have the genders of nouns like `die, der, das`, therefore it is easier for us to understand it. Often you also have to learn the government of the verb like `denken an`, `denken über`, `warten auf` or `sich wehren gegen`.

Comment: Pons dictionary indicates the case. Jdm is dative, jdn is accusative.  http://de.pons.com/übersetzung?q=Lieben&l=deen&in=de&lf=de

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Half of the answer has been given (`jdm` [or `jmdm`] Vs. `jdn`[or `jmdn`]).

Here two other points to consider.

- First, the answer is a little grammar as well. Not all verbs have a fixed case; for instance *waschen*:

  > Ich wasche etwas <sup><sup>Akk.</sup></sup>.

  but

  > Ich wasche mir <sup><sup>Dat.</sup></sup> die Hände.

  So you might have to do the analysis by yourself.
- Second, *etw* and *sich* are also an indicators of dative and accusative. You might also find in dictionaries then

  > `verb` + *etw.*<sup><sup>Akk.</sup></sup>

  or

  > sich<sup><sup>Dat.</sup></sup> `verb`

By the way, don't neglect genitive-objects ;) Not the best way to perform the search, but [this one](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/jds.+etw..html) gives you lot of them. Their register is usually *gehoben*.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by etwas and sich are indicators. In dict.cc I see a lot of etwas. Does it tell me which Kasus to use?

Comment: @Menny Well, *sich* and *etwas* tell you you have to use Akk. or Dat. but in dict.cc they don't, to my knowledge, put a superindex telling you which of them you have to use. You have to do the analysis.

Comment: Isn't it that "Ich wasche mir Die hände"  because "die Hände" is an accusative object so the reflexive part must be dative. Nothing to do with a "rule" about waschen taking dative.

Comment: @HörmannHH  I don't see any exclusion, because you can "einen Esel jemanden beschimpfen".

Answer (score 5):

dict.cc uses `jdn` to indicate accusative (for example, see [dict.cc on "lehren"](http://www.dict.cc/?s=lehren&=DEEN&=)) and `jdm`for dative (see [dict.cc on "ausweichen", e.g.](http://www.dict.cc/?s=ausweichen)). But the indicator may be missing, cf. [dict.cc on "verzeihen"](http://www.dict.cc/?s=verzeihen). Often, the example sentences are giving a hint which grammatical case to use. There's also an [explanation of the abbreviations used](http://contribute.dict.cc/guidelines/) (but this tells only that `jdn` means "jemanden", but doesn't explain why those indicators are added to the verbs).

Comment: Rule of thumb: `n` vs `m` is Akkusativ vs Dativ, that is "jemande(n/m)" is the Akkusativ/Dativ form of "jemand". It's added just like `sb.` and `sth.` in English.

Answer (score 2):

You can also look up the verb in the free [Pons online dictionary](http://de.pons.com/). (Pons is one of the better known publishers of dictionaries in Germany). It will list many (but not all) verb patterns, with "jdn/jdm" or "Akk./Dat." etc. for the cases. I recommend learning the patterns and the associated meaninings instead of just the verb (in the same way English students have to learn "to put up with s.th." instead of just "put", you learn "sich (Akk) mit jdm/etw abfinden" instead of "abfinden").

For prepositions that don't belong to a specific verb pattern, [mein-deutschbuch](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=14) has some good lists.

Answer (score 0):

The basic difference to determine the case a verb needs to take is by knowing whether the verb has movement or not. Verbs that have movement take the akkusative case whereas the verbs that are stationary and do not show movement take dative case.