# Use of personal pronouns (including the polite forms)

Tags: personal-pronoun

I need some help/sources for grammar exercises regarding personal pronouns.
I don't know when to use *Ihnen, ihr, ihrem, ihm* and so on.

For example:

> Ich habe Sie angerufen, um zu fragen, ob Sie Anstellung von Personal machen?

Is the first "Sie" correct?

Comment: Your question is very general and the use of personal pronouns is documented very well on the [Internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_pronouns). Try reading the full article and then maybe you can come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Although if you do not have any access to German grammar explained in your native language, I will be happy to help.

Comment: Ok tank you...in my example "Ich habe Sie angerufen, um zu fragen, ob Sie Anstellung von Personal machen?" Is it correct the first "Sie" ?? thanks :)

Comment: The first part of your sentence is correct. In order to keep a good portion of your sentence, I would do it so: Ich habe Sie angerufen, um zu fragen, ob Sie Personal einstellen.

Comment: I am new here, and I don't know how is this site working....I wanted to go to chat but it didn't allow me because I don't have 20 points I think....how is this working? there so many things here..uff

Comment: You can take the [tour](http://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @TimeeaAugustin calm down... I suggest you take a small detour through the [help] after doing the tour Carlster suggested. You will find most of what you are looking for there. For all else you can ask questions on [meta] or [meta.se] for that mattter

Comment: @hellcode I think you considered "Sie" als plural, otherwise your sentence is incorrect. In that case either "...ob sie Personal einstellen" or "...ob Sie Personal einstellt".

Comment: @Em1: "Sie" is an address pronoun. Not plural.

Comment: @hellcode Oh yes, right. My second example is indeed wrong. I confused it with Spanish where the third-person conjugation is identical to the address pronoun. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personal pronouns like proper nouns follow the same inflection rules, as is nicely summarized in a table here: [canoonet: Personal Pronouns](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Pers.html?lang=en)

The polite form in adressing people actually is the 3rd person form capitalized. The same inflection rules apply.

Now we have to **learn by heart** which grammatical case goes with any verb. There are no generally valid rules for this. For anrufen it would be the accusative:

> Ich rufe Sie (*accustive*) an.

The example you gave with *anrufen* is a nice example of inconsistent rules. The correct grammatical case is accusative case but you will also hear the dative in southern regions of Germany and in Switzerland (**wrong:** *"Ich rufe Ihnen an"*).

With a verb taking another grammatical case (e.g. *zustimmen* taking the dative) you'd say:

> Ich stimme Ihnen (*dative*) zu.

Also see the following related questions:

- [Recommended ways to learn the cases?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2479/recommended-ways-to-learn-the-cases)
- [How to look up whether a verb uses dative or accusative](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/12038/how-to-look-up-whether-a-verb-uses-dative-or-accusative)
- [Dictionary abbreviation meanings: "jdm", "jdn", "etw",](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6856/dictionary-abbreviation-meanings-jdm-jdn-etw)

Comment: I think "zuhören" requires dative. For comparison: Ich höre seiner zu. In this case (and the previous) "Ihr/Ihrer" is a possessive pronoun (accusative/dative).

Comment: @Carlster Nun ja - ich frage nach **wessen** Vorlesung und nicht  nach *wem seine*... aber mit dem Possesivpronomen hast Du natürlich recht. Vielleicht verwirrt das nur (von Antwort gelöscht).

Comment: "Seiner" soll in meinem Gegenbeispiel der Genitiv von "er" sein.

Comment: Geeignete Beispiele gehen mit Verben einher, die den Genitiv verlangen, wie zB "gedenken".

Comment: Richtig ist: Ich höre ihm zu. Hier sieht man, dass "zuhören" mit dem Dativ kommt. Unpraktischerweise sind für weibliche Sachen der 2. & 3. Fall des Pos.pron. "Ihr" gleich.